# How to convert a Scanned PDF file using Foxit Libraries

Tags: vba, pdf, ocr, foxit, foxitembeddedsdk

My question is simple and clear. I find that nobody else seems to have this problem. I insist to use ***Foxit*** libraries because it supports Farsi text recognition. My programming language is VBA.

Comment: This post looks like it has working code  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140536/merge-pdf-files-with-vba-and-foxit

Comment: But it seems that it didn't say anything about **conversion**

Comment: This post looks more promising though  ...  https://kb.foxit.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040660351-How-to-edit-or-change-scan-based-PDF-?utm_source=googleads&utm_medium=Shopping&cq_cmp=17931245485&utm_campaign=FOXIT_GA_EU1_EN_PMAX_REVENUE_ONLINE%20STORE_PDF%20EDITOR&gclid=CjwKCAiArY2fBhB9EiwAWqHK6mAbZMGvMV7gPcTtlKFJNfVJqYavss-3GeYFmvsLSFSvRoIqyJWSfxoCHVMQAvD_BwE

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it pragmatically.

Comment: I tried their SDK but there is no OCR tools or methods in that library too. The closest thing that I could find to gets me near to my goal (But not exactly) is `.OCRAndExportToExcel` method of `FoxitPhantomPDF` library. But as the name suggests it always make an Excel file and OCR operations is not visible in PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no method neither in `PhantomPDF` nor in `FoxIt SDK` Libraries to only OCR a PDF file without saving it as Excel file afterwards.